# Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Возможным вариантом модернизации существующих газораспределительных сетей низкого давления для повышения эффективности и надежности работы ГПО является повышение давления на выходе группового поселкового ГРП до 30…50 мбар и более (,) с предварительной установкой на входе в дома потребителей СДГ, понижающих давление на входе в ГПО до требуемых 20 мбар.

Answer (score 1):

Оборот "для повышения эффективности и надежности работы ГПО" я бы выделил двумя тире или даже заключил в скобки (запятые здесь не подходят). Он в развёрнутом виде поясняет, для чего (в каком направлении) модернизация, и вставлен в основное утверждение о содержании модернизации. Без такого выделения при чтении сложно отстроиться, напр., от последовательности слов "сетей низкого давления для повышения эффективности" (появляется ложная сущность). Запятую, которая у вас в скобках, я бы тоже поставил: в том месте обязательна речевая пауза, а следующая далее часть описывает условия, выполнение которых должно предварять упомянутое "повышение давления". Такие обособления могут сделать фразу более удобной для восприятия.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше скобки. Указанная запятая нужна.